# How do I get the 'package' task in my project

Tags: scala, sbt

In apparently the 0.7 format of sbt projects a user might create a project with the following information:

From a text editor, create a project file
`project/build/Project.scala` with the following contents:

```
import sbt._ 
class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {
  override def artifactID = "MyProj1"
}
```

However, the new format of (0.10 and 0.11 versions of sbt) might look more like:

At `project/Build.scala` put:

```
import sbt._
object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
}
```

However, when I use this new format, this type of project doesn't give you the `package` and `deploy` tasks, so how can I get those *back*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `package` should work, but for deploy maybe you want to try `publish`:
https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Publishing

There is a migration guide for switching from 0.7 to 0.11:
https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Migrating-from-SBT-0.7.x-to-0.10.x